# Magento 2 Enterprise edition Staging is not applying for sales price rule

Tags: magento2

I have added some campaigns for the sales price rule. But even after start date it is not applying. I have executed the indexer, cron and flush the cache but still it is showing the Upcoming.

You can see the screenshot

[image]

Can you please help me to find the reason? Thank you very much.